# Skip unwanted returns in a recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I have a problem with following challenge:

Two players (numbered 1 and 2) are playing a game with n stones. Player 1 always plays first, and the two players move in alternating turns. The game's rules are as follows:

In a single move, a player can remove either 2,3 or 5 stones from the game board.
If a player is unable to make a move, that player loses the game.
Given the number of stones, find and print the name of the winner (i.e.,First  or Second) on a new line. Each player plays optimally, meaning they will not make a move that causes them to lose the game if some better, winning move exists.

(Output Format

On a new line for each test case, print "First" if the first player is the winner; otherwise, print "Second".)

Example:

amount = 7, player = 1.

calling getWinner(7-5,-1)

amount = 2, player = -1

calling getWinner(2-2,1)

amount= 0, player = 1

The function should not return anything here,because it would abort the search, but I am forced by the compiler to add a return statement.

```
 public static String getWinner(int amount, int player){
    if (amount == 0 || amount == 1){
         if (player == -1) {
            return "First";                 
        }
    } else if (amount-5 >=0){
        return getWinner(amount-5,-player);
    } else if (amount-3 >=0) {
        return getWinner (amount-3,-player);
    } else if(amount-2 >= 0){
        return getWinner (amount -2 , -player);
    } else {
        return "Second";
    }
    return "failure";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code doesn't make sense since you are never actually choosing anything but do whatever comes first. Also for every step of a game it might be that some choices makes you loose and some makes you win so you need to know what you'd like.

You need to follow either 2, 3, or 5 based upon that the opponent looses.

```
private static boolean wins(int amount){
    if (amount < 0 ) {
        return true;  // game already over, previous player lost
    } else if ( amount <= 1){
        return false; // you loose always
    } else {
        // we win if the opponent doesn't
        return  wins(amount-5) == false ||
                wins(amount-3) == false ||
                wins(amount-2) == false;
    }
}
```

As you can see the default case does or between recursions. It stops for the very first recursion that becomes false and the result would be true, false otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that when the first condition (`amount == 0 || amount == 1`) is true, you don't always return (you only return if `player==-1`), so as far as the compiler is concerned, not all branches of the `if`-`else if`-...-`else` statement return a value, which is why you are forced to add a return statement as the last statement of the method.

You can re-write the logic as follows to eliminate the `return "failure"` :

```
 public static String getWinner(int amount, int player){
     if (amount == 0 || amount == 1){
         if (player == -1) {
             return "First";                 
         } else {
             return "Second";
         }
     } else if (amount-5 >=0){
         return getWinner(amount-5,-player);
     } else if (amount-3 >=0) {
         return getWinner (amount-3,-player);
     } else { // you no longer need the else if(amount-2 >= 0) condition
              // since it must be satisfied at this point
         return getWinner (amount -2 , -player);
     }
 }
```

Another alternative :

```
public static String getWinner(int amount, int player){
    if ((amount == 0 || amount == 1) && player == -1) {
        return "First";
    } else if (amount-5 >=0) {
        return getWinner(amount-5,-player);
    } else if (amount-3 >=0) {
        return getWinner (amount-3,-player);
    } else if(amount-2 >= 0) {
        return getWinner (amount -2 , -player);
    } else {
        return "Second";
    }
}
```

Comment: If we were in the given example, this would return "Second", but there might be a solution for Player1 in the other recursion branches(amount-3 ; amount-2). By returning "Second", no other branches would be searched anymore.

Comment: @ConradAshton I'm not sure what the logic is. I was assuming that once you reach `1` or `0` the winner is determined by the value of `player`.

Comment: @ConradAshton You can also change the first condition to `if ((amount == 0 || amount == 1)) && player == -1)`, and leave the rest of your logic (except of the `return "failure";`) as is.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I have updated the problem description for more details.